# symfony2 DataTransformer outside a form

Tags: design-patterns, symfony

my scenario is the next. What I want to know is a good way to design and organize my code.

I have a REST API which allows to retrieve or store some data. I have my set of Entity classes which represents my model but, as usual, the JSON objects the API sends or receives haven't the same attributes as the Entity classes.
For example:

```
Person (id, name, creationDate, lastModifDate)
```

When I user request a Person with ID=10, I don't want to return the `lastModifDate` attrib.

Si I'm thinking to create some kind of "transformator" or "conversor" between JSON objects the API revices/sends and my Entity model.

Which strategies do you recommend?

- DataTransformer, but I don't want to use forms
- ParamConverter, only helpful for the data received not for the data to be send.
- Create some DTO or VO that represents my Entities (without the undesired attributes to return) and create some "converter" classes (similar to the DataTransformer) which are responsible to:

  - Convert from JSON data to VO and from VO to Entity.
  - convert from Entity to VO and from VO to JSON data.

Any advises and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You could create a utility service that would take JSON as input parameter, and return entity object. Inside that service you just create new instance of your entity object, populate properties and return it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) you can use FormTypes and the whole form component for the input conversion. The fields in the form types, define the fields which a user can submit via POST/PUT. The same as in a web form.

For outputs, use the JMSSerializerBundle with serilisationGroups (also supported in FOSRestBundle in the view listener).

And take a look at this excellent blog post: [REST APIs with Symfony2: The Right Way](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/)